# Comparing set of bits in byte array

Tags: c#-3.0, arrays, bit

I have a byte array, as follows:

`byte[] array = new byte[] { 0xAB, 0x7B, 0xF0, 0xEA, 0x04, 0x2E, 0xF3, 0xA9};`

The task is to find the quantity of occurrences '0xA' in it.
Could you advise what to do? The answer is 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat the entire array as a single bit-string:

```
0xAB,    0x7B,    0xF0,    0xEA,    0x04,    0x2E,    0xF3,    0xA9 is then:
10101011 01111011 11110000 11101010 00000100 00101110 11110011 10101001
====                         ====                              ====
  ====                         ====                              ====
```

This has 1010 occurring 6 times.

If you don't try to match across byte boundaries, you could try something like the following (tested in Perl and translated by hand):

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
{
    for (int bits = 0xA0, mask = 0xF0; bits >= 0x0A; bits >>= 1, mask >>= 1)
    {
        if ((array[i] & mask) == bits)
            ++counter;
    }
}
```

To match across byte boundaries, you have to shift the bits in from the next byte.  Try something like this (tested in Perl and translated by hand):

```
int counter = 0;
byte tester = array[0];

for (int i = 1; i < array.length + 1; ++i)
{
    byte nextByte = i < array.length ? array[i] : 0;

    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; ++bit)
    {
        if ((tester & 0xF0) == 0xA0)
            ++counter;

        tester <<= 1;
        if ((nextByte & 0x80) != 0)
            tester |= 1;

        nextByte <<= 1;
    }
}
```

Both programs count 6 as there are no 1010 sequences across byte-boundaries in this example.

Comment: No, they have. The point is:
first element in array is 10101011. It means that it has at least 2
1010 (8-4 bits) and 1010 (6-2 bits).
I should check for each occurrence. The problem is that I cannot go outside byte boundaries.

Comment: I should find 1010 (this is 0xA).

Comment: So I should check first 4 bits (8-5) then I should shift (?) right and compare another 4 bits. And I should do it up to end of the array.
I tried to work with BitArray: BitArray arr = new BitArray(array);
But couldn't comnpare.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this example doesn't work.
It found 17 occurrences instead of 6.

Comment: if (nextByte & 0x80 != 0) - this part should be ((nextByte & 0x80) != 0) for != - has more priorite against &

Comment: I forgot that I needed to say: " (array[i] & 0xF0) == 0xA0  "  I discovered this when I actually tried running first program :)

Comment: ((array[i] & mask) == bits) Seems the same :)

Comment: By the way, could you explain what is happening there?

Comment: You're looking for 1010 bit patterns so you AND with the mask 1111 so that all other bits are set to zero, then you see if what remains is 1010

Comment: Thanks! Does it go outside the boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

So from your comment, you want the total count of appearances of the bit pattern `1010` in the bytes in your array.

For a given byte `b`, the count is the sum of

```
(b & 0x0A) == 0x0A ? 1 : 0
(b & 0x14) == 0x14 ? 1 : 0
(b & 0x28) == 0x28 ? 1 : 0
(b & 0x50) == 0x50 ? 1 : 0
(b & 0xA0) == 0xA0 ? 1 : 0
```

(left as an exercise: what is this doing?)

Put this in a function, call it for each byte in the array, sum the results.